# How to pipe a list of domain names into NSLookup using powershell?

Tags: networking, dns, powershell

I have a list of domain names in excel (100 in total) that look like the following:

```
domainnameone.com
otherdomainnametwo.com

etc'
```

I need to take this list and add exceptions into our firewall rules, but I need a list of IP Addresses to do it. How would I pipe this list into NSLOOKUP to receive a list back of all of the IP Addresses from the domain names?

Comment: Someone will provide a powershell answer, but this probably isn't the best way of going about doing this.  Many sites have hundreds of IP addresses (eg Facebook) that change all the time. If they are on a CDN like Akamai, then they might share IP addresses with other sites you might not want to block.  Consider using a proxy server and blocking at the URL level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not disagree at all with milli, for the sake of the questions I'd like to provide an answer. Powershell has built in tools which can achieve this without the use of `nslookup`. You can achieve what you're looking for by running the following

```
$servers = get-content "LIST_OF_DOMAINS_FILE_LOCATION"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server) | select IPAddressToString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a terrible idea.  Don't do that.**  Use a web proxy to allow connections to these domains by URL.  The IP addresses can change at any time, especially with large replicated web farms and cloud-based web services, so unless you are going to re-run your script every 5 minutes to pick up changes and update the firewall rules, and/or take a ton of support calls as these sites move... just don't solve it this way.  You will be dramatically jeopardizing your job security.

Comment: While the sentiment is correct, this does not answer the question asked.